# Checking if Username already exists

Tags: php

I currently have this code that I wrote up:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$rpassword = $_POST['rpassword'];
$usrip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$errors = array();
$checkUsername = $odb -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username");
$checkUsername -> execute(array(':username' => $username));
$countUsername = $checkUsername -> fetchColumn(0);
if ($checkUsername != 0)
{
$errors['Username is already taken'];
}
```

However it seems to just completely ignore this and even if the username is identical (capitals and such) it will still allow the user to register making 2 of the same users. My database looks like this:

http://puu.sh/1mTcZ/9b2ff3b68f44b4cc486beacc2d2b88fd

I cant seem to get this working at all. The database structure looks like this:
refined (dbname) > users (table) > username (row)

Any help is very much appreciated.

Edit:

After a few changes this is what I have, however I still seem to be having the same issues.

```
$checkUsername = $odb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE LOWER(`username`) = :username");
$checkUsername -> execute(array(':username' => $username));
$countUsername = $checkUsername -> fetchColumn(0);
if ($checkUsername != 0)
{
$errors['Username is already taken'];
}
```

The username row is also now utf8_general_ci

Comment: Your IF statement evaluates ($checkUsername != 0).  Shouldn't this be ($countUsername != 0) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I'll post my comment as an answer.

Your IF statement is evaluating the incorrect variable.  It should be evaluating $countUsername, not $checkUsername.

Also, you seem to be initializing your errors array incorrectly.  Try:

```
if ($countUsername != 0)
{
    $errors[] = 'Username is already taken';
}
```

I've tested this on my database and it works.

```
Collation = latin1_general_cs    (cs = case sensitive)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to set up table collation to 'utf8_general_ci'.
Also you can change your sql query to

```
$checkUsername = $odb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE LOWER(`username`) = :username");
```

Comment: Would this cause an issue with it thinking it's not already registered if the username has a capital? our current database has mixed caps/nocaps in usernames.

Comment: function LOWER will set all data in that field in lowercase before it will check with posted value, which You also can convert to lowercase

Comment: example: table contains 3 fields with values - Login, loGIN, login when you convert them to lowarcase it will be the same 'login'

Comment: I still seem to be having issues, I have http://pastebin.com/wiwZuhry currently. I even tried using countUsername instead however it still seems to be registering fine.

Comment: TRY THIS: if ( (int)$countUsername > 0 ) {
 $errors['Username is already taken'];
}